# QLineEdit could not set shortcuts when it's in focus

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qlineedit

I'm implementing a text-based to-do program. I have a `CommandInput` widget which inherits from `QLineEdit`. Basically there are a few commands, starting with keywords "add", "delete", "edit", and a few more.

I want to implement a few shortcuts.

1. `Ctrl+A` so that when the widget has focus, I can `setText("add \"\"")`, cursor at the second last position, so it appears to be `add "|"`
2. `Tab` so that when the widget has focus, when the user types in the first keyword, for example, `add`, then I can complete the command to `add "|"`

The key problem is that when the widget has focus, the shortcuts are not working. I've tried the following ways:

1/ Override `keyPressEvent`. The `Tab` key does not work as intended. And even if it works, I don't know how to do that for a keySequence like `Ctrl+A`.

```
void CommandInput::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *keyEvent)

{
    switch(keyEvent->key())
    {
    case Qt::Key_Tab;
        emit add_activated();
    default:
        QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(keyEvent);
    }
}
```

2/ Create shortcuts when initializing. This doesn't work either.

```
CommandInput::CommandInput(QWidget *parent)
    : QLineEdit(parent)
{
    tab_shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence("Tab"),this);
    add_shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+A"),this);

    connect(tab_shortcut, SIGNAL(activated()),
            this, SIGNAL(tab_activated()));
    connect(add_shortcut, SIGNAL(activated()),
            this, SIGNAL(add_activated()));
}
```

Hope you could help me on this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding `keyPressEvent` is probably the preferred approach here.  I'm going to guess that the reason why "Tab" doesn't work as expected is because you don't have a `break` statement after emitting `add_activated()`.  For "Ctrl+A", you'll have to look at the `modifiers()` for the key event.  As such, your `keyPressEvent` would look something like this:

```
void CommandInput::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* keyEvent)
{
   if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
   {
      emit add_activated();
   }
   else if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_A && 
            keyEvent->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier)
   {
      // Code for Ctrl+A goes here.
   }
   else
   {
      QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(keyEvent);
   }
}
```

This seems to work on my (Linux) machine.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!! All the combination keys are working now. Although the "Tab" is still not working, I've opted to go for an alternative way, using LeftQuotation instead. Thanks!=)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the Tab key working, I had to catch the keyPressEvent within event(), like this:

```
bool MyQTextBox::event(QEvent* event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) { // this did the trick for me
        this->keyPressEvent(dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event));
        return true;
    }
    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```